# css triangle top with rounded bottom with different colour

Tags: css

How do I add a rounded bottom with a different colour to a triangle?

```
 #box {
    content:"";
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 150px 150px 150px;
    border-color: transparent yellow red blue;
    position: relative;
 }
```

Produces:

[image: css output]

What I need is a green section on the bottom, with rounded corners:

[image: Desired output]

Comment: Maybe SVG could be a solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this will help you

```
#box {
    content:"";
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 150px 150px 150px;
    border-color: transparent yellow red blue;
    position: relative;
 }
 #box:before{
    content: '';
    width: 300px;
    height:  300px;
    display: block;
    background-color:green;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    left: -150px;
    z-index: -1;
 }
```

**Snippet:**

```css
#box {
    content:"";
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 150px 150px 150px;
    border-color: transparent yellow red blue;
    position: relative;
 }
 #box:before{
   content: '';
   width: 300px;
   height:  300px;
   display: block;
   background-color:green;
   border-radius: 50%;
   position: absolute;
   left: -150px;
   z-index: -1;
 }
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
```

Check the **[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3fLp4t37/)**

Comment: Whenever you can add SO snippet, please use that instead of jsFiddle, by the way you got my upvote.

Comment: @divy3993 Thank you, will use next time :)

Comment: there is no need of a pseudo element ;) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35421736/how-to-achieve-this-visual-using-css/35422035#35422035 radius and gradient will do the job on themselves extra styling such as shadows can be added too ;)

Answer (score 2):

```css
.bottom {
  height: 150px;
  width: 300px;
  background:green;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 300px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 300px;
}

 #box {
    content:"";
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 150px 150px 150px;
    border-color: transparent yellow red blue;
 }
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>

<div class="bottom"></div>
```

Comment: Works, but was restricted to just adding css, and not an extra div tag!

Comment: okay. use @Justin answer is sutable for your senario.